# EF Core creates duplicate changes for each new migration

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, database-migration

I designed my database through my model classes and enums, I’m using an enum for status values:

```cs
    public enum MyStatusEnum
     {
          Requested = 1,
          Validated = 2,
          Rejected = 3,
          Deleted = 4
     }
```

My class where I reference the enum for my PrimaryKey

```cs
     public class MyClientStatus
     {
          public MyStatusEnum MyClientStatusId { get; set; }
          // other stuff here ...
     }
```

Then I map between the enum and the type I want to store in my db (byte):

```cs
     modelBuilder.Entity<MyClientStatus>(entity =>
     {
         //map enum to byte for the primary MyClientStatusId 
         entity.Property(e => e.MyClientStatusId ).HasConversion<byte>();
    
         entity.Property(e => e.ConsumerStatusId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    
         // seed MyClientStatus values
         entity.HasData(Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyStatusEnum)).Cast<MyStatusEnum>().Select(e => new MyClientStatus() { MyClientStatusId = e, Label = e.ToString() }));
     });
```

After all that I start my new Migration with `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate`  and a new .cs file is well created with all dependencies, for example:

```cs
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "MyClientStatus",
            columns: table => new
            {
                MyClientStatusId = table.Column<byte>(nullable: false)
             },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_ClientStatus", x => x.MyClientStatusId);
                });
          //other stuff here ...
    }
```

I update my database and **until now all is good**, my **problem** is when I update an other class or I start a new migration **always it detects new changes according to my enum and my class**  :

```cs
     public partial class SecondMigration: Migration
        {
           protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
           {
               migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<byte>(
                name: "MyClientStatusId",
                table: "MyClientStatus",
                nullable: false,
                oldClrType: typeof(byte),
                oldType: "tinyint")
                .OldAnnotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1");             
           }
        }
```

I didn't find why exactly it detects these changes for each new migration (and of course I can't apply it because in my db the ClientStatus table is already as expected with a `MyClientStatusId(PK, tinyint, not null)` )

Can you please challenge me with your ideas

Thank you!

Comment: I'm wondering if it has to do with the provided ValueConverter via HasConversion<byte>(). According to their [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions#built-in-converters), there isn't a enum to byte conversion or vice versa. You can create your own custom ValueConverter tho that handles this.

Comment: @BenSampica you mean create a custom ValueConverter to convert enum to byte? is it possible?

Comment: Yes exactly. In the docs I linked it provides an example

Comment: @BenSampica I tried this and I got the same behavior `var statusConverter = new ValueConverter<MyStatusEnum, byte>(v => (byte)v, v => (MyStatusEnum)v);`